# SQL to try and eliminate duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to write some SQL that will allow me to eliminate duplicate rows.  Not all of the rows in the data set are duplicated.  I'm having some trouble.

This is the SQL that I have managed to create that finds me the maximum value of each duplicate row.  What I want is the other values besides the maximum.  The eventual goal is to delete those other values.

```
select 
    max(i.id) as max_id
    --.i.RotationDate
    --, i.Lastname
    --, i.Firstname
    --, i.Rotation
    --, max(i.created) as max_created
from Rotation_v2 i
group by i.rotationdate, i.lastname, i.firstname, i.rotation
having count(i.rotation) > 1
```

The plan was originally to do a delete wrapped around it using "IN", but that grabs all of the other rows that I want to keep. The ones that are not duplicated.

Here's some example data (which has been modified to protect privacy):

```
id  RotationDate    Lastname    Firstname   Rotation        Created
12462   20190802    Other       Person      PT DAY OFF      2019-06-30 11:47:26.000
12463   20180315    Other       Person      MSM MSO CALL    2019-07-19 08:50:47.000
12464   20180315    Other       Person      MSM MSO CALL    2019-07-19 09:50:47.000
12465   20190802    Still       More        LONG ROTAT      2019-06-30 11:47:26.000
12466   20190323    Again       Guy         MSM MSO CALL    2019-06-30 22:45:28.000
12467   20190323    Again       Guy         MSM MSO CALL    2019-06-30 23:45:28.000
```

In this case, I want to delete rows with ID 12463 and 12466 only.

Comment: can you define *duplicates* in your context?

Comment: If you define your table with a correct primary key, you will not get this. To handle it without a pk, you need to create a trigger before insert.

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala in my example, I classify a duplicate as the same rotation date, lastname, firstname and rotation.  The ID is always unique and the Created is a timestamp of whenever that row was added to the table.

Comment: @Fallenreaper The ID column in this case is the primary key.

Comment: You can also make a unique key by linking columns together in SQL, which would go into the table definition.  That could also save on instances of "these already exist"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `row_number()`

```
   delete from a
    (select *,row_number() over(partition by RotationDate,Lastname,Firstname,Rotation
    order by Created ) rn
    from table
    ) a  where a.rn>1
```

Comment: if OP want last one, probably `order by Created desc`

Comment: @Zaynul Thank you for that!  It's so much more simple an elegant than what I had been trying to put together. :-)

Comment: As it turns out, while my experiments using a select instead of a delete worked great, doing a delete isn't actually supported by the version of SQL Server I'm on.  (I think it's 2012).  Any thoughts on modifying the above so that I can use it with 2012?

Answer (score 0):

For those interested, this is the query that I managed to get working in SQL 2012...

```
delete from a
from
(
    select 
        *,
        row_number() 
    over (partition by RotationDate, Lastname, Firstname, Rotation order by Created ) rn
    from Rotation_v2
) a  
where a.rn > 1
```